# website event countdown timer with server sided event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

i'm working on a website. I need to add a timer to the page which counts down from for example : DD::hh:mm 02:12:34 to 0. once the timer hits 0, a query has to be sent to the database to notify it that the timer has ended.

How would i be able to make this timer?

also, the query at the end of the timer count down has to be sent regardless of current open sessions. (so also with 0 active sessions the event still needs to be handled)

edit: i don't have a machine to run a timer program

Comment: Why you need that countdown timer ? You can check it when you need the value of the database and calculate everything...

Comment: @M4HdYaR i need it to display it to users

Comment: so update the database when you want to display it to users and use javascript or AJAX to make it realtime

Comment: @M4HdYaR what about an endpoint datetime in the db, query that for every user, and then calculate the remaining time to show on their client sided timer?

Comment: Yes it's the way php works

Comment: @M4HdYaR alright, thank you! i will try that.

Comment: if it worked please tell me to post it as an answer so other people can use it too.

Comment: @M4HdYaR i will, however it might take a while

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use php script for that called by Ajax. To `initializeClock()` function jus put deadtime you want execute MySQL query.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        initializeClock('timerView', '2018-8-26 14:12:00');
    });
</script>

<div id="messages"></div>
<div id="timerView"></div>
<div id="quiz_body"></div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
// This function just call the php script over Ajax to execute MySQL query...
var queryToDb = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/mysql.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        data: {
            done: true
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#quiz_body').html(response);
            startTimer();
        },
        error: function (xhr, type, exception) {
            var _msg = "Service through error: (" + xhr.status + ") " + exception.toString();
            var _err = $('#messages');
            _err.text(_msg).show();
        }
    });
}

// return apropriate countdown information as hour, minutes, sec...
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}

// initialize countdown...
function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var timeinterval = setInterval(function () {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
        clock.innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
            'hours: ' + t.hours + '<br>' +
            'minutes: ' + t.minutes + '<br>' +
            'seconds: ' + t.seconds;
        if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
            queryToDb();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

mysql.php

```
<?php

if($_POST){
    // Create mysql conection and query here...
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','dbname');

    // Check for errors
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // Do query if a connection has success...
    $result = $db->query("INSERT INTO table (some_name) VALUES ('Some value');");
    if($result){
        $db->close();
        die('OK');
    }else{
        die($someErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

An alternative is call an API instead of call Ajax.

Comment: It is not server sided.